# Sharepoint Explorer View Some of Files Disappear

Tags: sharepoint

I have 5 folders in my document library (sharepoint 2013). There are almost 10 files in each folder.

When I click "Open with Explorer", I can see all 5 folders in explorer view. But problem is when I go in 2 of folders, there is no files. Files be disappear in explorer view.

I have added new files in those 2 folders. Same thing happen. Files be disappear in explorer view.

I can see all files in browser.

Any suggestion?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Do you enable Check Out or versioning feature in the library?

Open the SharePoint library using a library owner, check the files which were disappear in Explorer view to see if the files are checked out. If yes, check in the files.

Then open the library in Explorer view, check the result.

An aritcle may help you:
https://community.spiceworks.com/topic/764438-closed-files-missing-hidden-from-sharepoint-2013-document-library